# (C++) How to convert a string into a character vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, vector

How to convert a string such as "Hello, world!" into a vector of characters? I've seen many techniques on how to do this for plain arrays, but none for vectors. Here is my code:

```
string raw_text = "Hello, world!";
vector<char> char_text;
```

Any way to make a character vector from raw_text?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify whether youwant the vector to contain a null terminator

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<char> char_text(raw_text.begin(), raw_text.end());
```